# Can the "limit laws" be generalized to applying any continuous function to a limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am starting calculus and have just learned the "limit laws": the limit of a sum of functions equals the sum of their limits, and likewise for difference, product, quotient, and so on.

Intuitively, it seems that:

$$\lim_{x \to c} g(f(x)) = g(\lim_{x \to c} f(x))$$

...As long as the function $g$ is continuous.

But I don't know if this is true, or how it could be proven. If it's not true, then there should be some stronger condition which makes it true, and which would generalize the "limit laws" to any operation which meets some criteria (not just the operations of addition, multiplication, etc).

Can someone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a result, which states that:

> If $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=b$, $\lim_{y\to b} g(y)=c$ and $g$ is continuous at $b$, then $$\lim_{x\to a} g(f(x))=c$$

which it's easily proven using the $\delta-\varepsilon$ definition of limit:

Fix $\varepsilon>0$.

- As $\lim_{y\to b} g(y)=c$, there is $\eta>0$ so that
  $$|y-b|<\eta \ \Rightarrow \ |g(y)-c|<\varepsilon$$
- now, as $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=b$, for the $\eta>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ so that 
  $$0<|x-a|<\delta\ \Rightarrow \ |f(x)-b|<\eta$$

so if $|x-a|<\delta, \ x\neq a$, then $|f(x)-b|<\eta$ and $|g(f(x))-c|<\varepsilon$. This proves that $\lim_{x\to a} g(f(x))=c$.

Note that $g$ must be continuous at $b$, or the result would be false.

Comment: Your general results require that your definition of limit takes into account the function's value at the point in question, which some sources do but others (most?) don't. Otherwise, it's not true, for example in case $f(x)=b$ for all $x$, and $g(b) \neq c = \lim_{x\to b} g(x)$.

Comment: If $f(x)=b$ for all $x$ and $g(b)\neq c = \lim_{x\to b} g(x)$, the framed statement is valid. It is not true that $\lim_{x\to a} g(f(x))=g\lim_{x\to a} f(x))$ because $g$ is not continuous at $b$.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "valid" here: In Hans' example, the hypotheses of your framed statement are true and the conclusion is not. You're right that this occurs because $g$ is discontinuous at $b$, but that seems to contradict your implicit assertion that $g$ need not be continuous at $b$, and doesn't address the OP's suspicion, which is correct: If $g$ is discontinuous at $b$, then there exists an $f$ with $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x) = b$ for which your framed statement is not valid. :)

Comment: I don't actually understand the counterexample. If $g$ is not defined in $b$, then the composition $g(f(x))$ for $f(x)=b$ is not defined, so it wouldn't make sense to even think of the limit $\lim_{x\to a} g(f(x))$. I'm not sure if this is what you are refering to.

Comment: It's not that $g(b)$ is undefined, it's that it has the “wrong” value. If $f(x)=b$ identically, then $g(f(x))=g(b)$ identically, which doesn't have the limit $c$ as $x \to a$, unless $g(b)=c$, i.e., if $g$ is continuous at $b$.

Comment: Some would get around this by saying that $\lim_{y\to b}g(y)$ doesn't exist in this situation. It all depends on whether you say “$|y-b|<\delta$” or “$0<|y-b|<\delta$” in your definition of limits. All I'm pointing out is that if you use the first definition (as some sources do), then your claim is true, but not if you use the second definition (as other sources do, and also you in the proof you have written).

Comment: But in the end, it doesn't matter when it comes to the important concept, which is continuity. Everyone agrees what the definition of continuous is, and that the composition of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: OK. I see it now. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome! So... my intuition was right, but this theorem is a little more general than the way I stated it?